# Given a byte array, how do I find out which compression algorithm was used?

Tags: sql-server, algorithm, compression, zlib

I have a bizzare task at hand. Is it possible to find out which method a file was compressed with given it's bytes?

For example, I have a byte stream that's supposedly from a file that's stored in a SQL Server database.

```
0x789CED7D07A015C5F5F7ECBDAFD20544A479A...
```

No one knows what this is. We're suspecting zlib but there are several methods of compression even amongst zlib.

Any guidance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's zlib ([RFC 1950](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1950.txt)).  What you provided decodes as a valid two-byte zlib header, and the beginning of a valid dynamic deflate block.